# Facebook photo upload using HTTP request in Java

Tags: java, facebook, http

I'm trying to upload a photo to my profile via HttpURLConnection.
I have the acces token for user_status,user_photos,offline_access,publish_stream

Samples from my code:

```
url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos");

String content =
    "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode ("my_token") +
    "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode ("SUNT  !!!")+
    "&url=" + URLEncoder.encode("file:///D:\\personale\\Images\\P0030_07-02-11_00.JPG");
```

When I make the request I got the following error

```
{"error":{"message":"file:\/\/\/D:\\personale\\Images\\P0030_07-02-11_00.JPG is an internal url, but this is an external request.","type":"CurlUrlInvalidException"}}
```

Can I upload files from my PC using the file URL ?
How can I upload files, using byte array from files ?

Many thanks !

Comment: `url` parameter designed for uploading of externally served images that publicly accessible. To upload local images you should use [`source`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) (instead of `url`) and it should contain `multipart/form-data` encoded image data.

Comment: Check [restfb](http://restfb.com/) or [spring-social-facebook](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/). They are Java wrappers of the Graph API that make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

[The solution, as posted by dnp](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9856667/2):

---

Many thanks !

This is the solution:

```
public class Main2 { 

static final String BOUNDARY = "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy"; 

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{ 
    URL url; 
    HttpURLConnection urlConn; 
    DataOutputStream printout; 
    DataInputStream input; 

    //------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    File image = new File("D:/personale/Images/P1025[01]_03-07-11.JPG"); 


    FileInputStream imgStream = new FileInputStream(image); 

    byte [] buffer = new byte[(int) image.length()]; 

    imgStream.read(buffer); 

    //------------------------------------------------------------------- 


    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.18.1.1", 4444)); 

    //url = new URL ("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"); 
    url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=AAACkMOZA41QEBACsafBxqVfXX54JqGLQSaE6YQ062NuTe3XUZBTdTEvy3R2H9Yr4PZA9r38JvLni7r1hYLuZCnBZAAPPH3krMMSKtIraiswZCiIZBu0nyYT"); 
    System.out.println("Before Open Connection"); 

    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy); 

    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + getBoundaryString()); 

    urlConn.setDoOutput (true); 
    urlConn.setUseCaches (false); 
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

   // String content = "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode ("AAACkMOZA41QEBAHQHUyYcMsLAewOYIe1j5dlOVOlMZBm6h9rvCQEFhmcBHg7ETHrdlrgv4sau573xMVuxIt8DzRxKFuqRqqBskDvOZA9iIkZCdPyI4Bu"); 

    String boundary = getBoundaryString(); 

    String boundaryMessage = getBoundaryMessage(boundary, "upload_field", "P1025[01]_03-07-11.JPG", "image/png"); 

    String endBoundary = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n"; 

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

    bos.write(boundaryMessage.getBytes()); 

    bos.write(buffer); 

    bos.write(endBoundary.getBytes()); 

    printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream ()); 

    //printout.writeBytes(content); 

    printout.write(bos.toByteArray()); 

    printout.flush (); 
    printout.close (); 
    // Get response data. 



    //input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getInputStream ()); 

    if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == 400 || urlConn.getResponseCode() == 500) { 
        input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getErrorStream()); 
    } else { 
        input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getInputStream()); 
    } 

    String str; 
    while (null != ((str = input.readLine()))) 
    { 
        System.out.println (str); 
    } 
    input.close (); 

} 

public static String getBoundaryString() 
{ 
    return BOUNDARY; 
} 

public static String getBoundaryMessage(String boundary, String fileField, String fileName, String fileType) 
{ 
    StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer("--").append(boundary).append("\r\n"); 
    res.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(fileField).append("\"; filename=\"").append(fileName).append("\"\r\n")  
        .append("Content-Type: ").append(fileType).append("\r\n\r\n"); 

    return res.toString(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: downvote for not explaining the solution. Source code is good, but not a reak answer

Comment: I think the code is borrowed from: http://www.thoughtwavesoft.com/cms/index.php?option=com_easyblog&view=entry&id=5&Itemid=102  The source must be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i am using this solution but it is saying : ' Connection timed out: connect'. Please Help

Comment: what is inetsocket address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following api to upload image on FB in default album

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/

The latest release version 3.0 has this feature.